# How do I animate a PathGeometry to show itself slowly?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, animation

Hi have the following piece of XAML

```
<Path Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeMiterLimit="4" Name="kvg_0994c_s1">
   <Path.Data>
      <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M28.27,12.64C28.32,13.27 28.52,14.32 28.17,15.16 25.86,20.7 19.22,31.55 9.81,39.71" />
   </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

I wish to animate the PathGemorty to reveal itself slowly (over 2 seconds or so). Basically the effect that I am after is drawing a line on the screen automatically, in particular the path that is specified in the code above.

I need to do this in C# code as I am loading the XAML dynamically from an external file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use WPF animation for it. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx  More information about animation you can find in excellent book "Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed" by Adam Nathan.
I think you can find exact answer on your question here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/19a7bd4b-cf28-4b31-a329-a5f58b9ec374

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by 'reveal itself slowly' ? You mean like it was drawn bit by bit ? Then you'll have to decompose the Data, then re-compose a geometry adding elements one by one. So you might, using the Path's name (kvg_0994c_s1) in code behind, (and assuming the Path.Data is always a PathGeometry, so you can cast it to PathGeometry) you get the PathGeometry.Figures in an initial List, then clear the figures in  the displayed Path. Then you set-up a timer (a DispatchTimer might be enough) to call a function every 200ms or so and in this function you add one by one the figures to the PathGeometry.Figures of the displayed path. You might have to adjust both the number of parts you add each time, and timer values to get the effect you want. And if you want constant 'speed' -> you have to compute the length of each part and adjust. But it might be nice to have non-constant speed to look more like hand-drawing.